# Efficiently Fixing Ownership, Group Membership, and Mode Problems on an Extremely Large NFS Share

Tags: linux, bash, find, nfs

I am fixing ownership, group membership, and mode problems in an entire directory tree (except for two particular subdirectories) accessible to me only via NFS. This directory tree contains tens of TB of data, so the commands to fix these issues are taking a very long time to run (I'm a full day in at this point on the first command, and I don't know how to gauge how far along the command is).

My first command is the following, used to make ownership and group membership fixes:

```
find /share \
\( \
   -type d -a \
   \( \
      -path /share/exclude_dir_1 -o \
      -path /share/exclude_dir_2 \
   \) -a \
   -prune \
\) -o \
\( \
   -type d -o \
   -type f \
\) \
-exec chown myuser:mygroup {} \;
```

My currently-planned commands, after the command above completes, to fix mode problems are as follows:

```
find /share \
\( \
   -type d -a \
   \( \
      -path /share/exclude_dir_1 -o \
      -path /share/exclude_dir_2 \
   \) -a \
   -prune \
\) -o \
-type d \
-exec chmod 775 {} \;

find /share \
\( \
   -type d -a \
   \( \
      -path /share/exclude_dir_1 -o \
      -path /share/exclude_dir_2 \
   \) -a \
   -prune \
\) -o \
-type f \
-exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

I currently have a 1 Gbps connection to the NFS share. That connection will soon be upgraded to 10 Gbps, though I am not sure if the network connection is where the bottleneck is.

I am using Bash, and I can execute these commands on either RHEL 6 or RHEL 7.

Does the community have suggestions on how this can be done more efficiently?

Secondarily, if the community has suggestions on how to gauge the progress of these commands, that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're running (or planning to run) uses one `chown` (or `chmod`) per file. The fact the directory "contains tens of TB of data" is not directly relevant; the total *number* of files is what counts. For few huge files your command(s) would finish quickly.

You operate remotely and "the connection will soon be upgraded to 10 Gbps". I think in a case of modifying metadata the latency is way more relevant than the throughput.

Possible improvements:

1. Working locally on the server.

   Compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398385/10765659):

   > NFS uses Filehandles; in order to do something to a file, a client first obtains a Filehandle through a LOOKUP, then the obtained Filehandle is used to perform the other requests. A minimum of two datagram is required, and the time between them can, in particular circumstances, be quite "large".

   I know you said "accessible to me only via NFS". In general however, working on the server without relying on NFS at all will probably outperform any other hint, especially if the latency is relatively high. Maybe you can ask the server administrator to run few commands for you.
2. Requesting many actions in parallel.

   Your code runs one `chown` (or `chmod`) at a time. Not only the network latency (packets travelling back and forth) but also syncing on the server will contribute to the overall delay between requesting a change and exiting with success (after receiving a confirmation from the server) and moving to the next file. See [this](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-nfs/msg46489.html):

   > All metadata operations such as `create`, `chmod`, `rename`, etc. will cause
   >   the server to flush the file metadata to disk assuming that you set
   >   the (highly recommended) `sync` export option. If `sync` is set, the
   >   server will also honour `COMMIT` requests by flushing the data to stable
   >   storage.

   `sync` is a server option (see `man 5 exports`).

   Imagine a single messenger travelling between two outposts. If the round-trip time is huge, it's reasonable to use many independent messengers for independent topics. In your case:

   - you can run few `find`s, each on its own branch of the directory tree in question;
   - or you can feed the output from `find` (no `-exec`) to `parallel` or `xargs -P`.

   Notes:

   - If you can work locally on the server then you don't need such parallelization.
   - If you overestimate the server's performance and send too many requests in parallel, you can inadvertently execute a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).
3. Ownership mapping.

   There is a way to map ownership on a client without altering it on the server. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/632315). In case the link breaks: the keyword is `idmapd` or `rpcidmapd`.

   Notes:

   - The server must cooperate.
   - This may eliminate the need for `chown` but not the need for `chmod`.
   - If there are other clients, they may need this solution as well.
4. Using `chown` recursively.

   Your code runs one `chown` per matching file. Spawning a process is costly, it's better to make one process deal with many files. Use `chown -R`; the option is required by POSIX thus portable.

   Notes:

   - This improvement is reasonable also when working locally on the server.
   - Because you need different modes for directories and regular files, it's not easy to make `chmod -R` similarly useful.
   - The need to exclude certain directories may interfere. Hint: if you can, bind mount a dummy (empty) directory over the directory you want to exclude to hide it from `chmod -R`.
5. Using `-exec … {} +`.

   Since `chmod -R` doesn't fit your needs, the next best thing is to run `chmod` with many operands. Instead of `-exec chmod 775 {} \;` run `-exec chmod 775 {} +`. Don't expect one `chmod` to do the entire job, there are limitations. `find` will respect the limitations and run as many `chmod`s as needed, still passing multiple operands to each.

   Notes:

   - This improvement is reasonable also when working locally on the server.
   - `parallel` or `xargs` can pass more than one argument to `chmod`. I won't elaborate on this.

Comment: Extremely helpful! Thank you!

Re file count vs. storage used: Correct. I'm sure you inferred I have *many* files.
Re latency: I am in a low-latency situation; at least I'm not being *harmed* there.
Re working on local server: No access; sys admin not an option
Re parallelization/single command with many operands: Looks like most benefit lies here; your response taught me much!
Re sync: Must be left on; share is constantly in use
Re owner mapping: No server cooperation
Re chown -R: Much benefit here too on subdirectories